# TypeError: Cannot read property 'capture' of undefined

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using the cordova Media Capture plugin but no possibility to make it work and I can't sort it out.

The error : `TypeError: Cannot read property 'capture' of undefined`

So here is the controller I am using for my Ionic app, nothing seems to work so far. Any idea ?

```
.controller('recordController', ['$scope', '$timeout', '$state', '$document', '$firebaseArray', 'CONFIG', function($scope, $timeout, $state, $document, $firebaseArray, CONFIG) {

  document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
    console.log(navigator.device.capture);
}

  var captureSuccess = function(e) {
      console.log('captureSuccess');console.dir(e);
      $scope.sound.file = e[0].localURL;
      $scope.sound.filePath = e[0].fullPath;
  }

  $scope.recordAudio = function() {
      navigator.device.capture.captureAudio(
          captureSuccess,captureError,{duration:10});
  }




  var a = document.getElementById('tags');
  a.addEventListener('keyup',addthis);

  function addthis() {
      b = a.value.replace('#','');
      a.value = '#'+b

      if (a.value.indexOf(' '))
      {
      a.value = a.value.replace(' ','#');
      }
  }    
}])
```

Comment: try just logging navigator.device and see what it is.

Comment: Hello, it doesn't display anything, nothing in the console at all...

Comment: The capture object needs to exist on the navigator.device object. If it doesn't exist then you should get the current exception, which indicates that the capture plugin is maybe not installed on your project ? Install it using : cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-media-capture (visit repo https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media-capture)

Comment: Yes I followed everything, it is installed and even when I build on Android, at installation it shows that the Audio Recorder is asking for permission... It  just fires this error systematically, whatever I define. And the listener for deviceready never fires and I don't know why...

Comment: maybe, define DeviceReady before addListener

Answer (score 0):

try installing the device plugin,

```
cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-device.git
```